# How to fix an error when typing ssh localhost in terminal?

Tags: ssh, error-handling, localhost, key

When I type ssh localhost command in terminal I face this error.

kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by ::1 port 22

Does anybody know how to resolve it? Thank you!

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questionds like this on [unix.se] or [su]. This is also a pretty common error and you should be able to find other questions on the same subject.

Comment: not posted on the right forum with very less details